# Perlbrew cannot download latest tarball

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I've installed perlbrew on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM, but I cannot download the latest version,

```
con@con-VirtualBox:~/20190305_concordance$ perlbrew install 5.28.1
```

gives error

```
Fetching perl 5.28.1 as /home/con/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.28.1.tar.gz
Download http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.28.1.tar.gz to /home/con/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.28.1.tar.gz
ERROR: Failed to download http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.28.1.tar.gz
```

Why is this happening? How can I get perlbrew to install the latest version?

Comment: Can you `curl` the file and get it? If not, there's a networking issue rather than a `perlbrew` one.

Comment: If `curl` works as per @JoeMcMahon's comment for `5.28.1` (which would indicate the network is ok), try installing a different version of perl with `perlbrew`.

Comment: yep, curl worked, maybe an issue with Perlbrew, I don't know

Comment: Are you using the latest version of perlbrew (0.86)?